# JQUERY - remove all words after character

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I need to remove and modify (email) usernames

examples:

```
1) max@custom.com
2) zulu-brain@some.com
3) top.master@other.com
```

should be result to:

```
1) max
2) zulubrain
3) topmaster
```

i have to remove all after @ character and clean special characaters like ".", "-", "#"

what is the best way?

a static example:

```
var username = "max@custom.com";
username.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
```

should clean the name but how can i remove all after "@" ?

Comment: Just take the substring up until the index of the `@` character and use your existing regex on that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [**.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to extract name then do the cleanup operation using existing code.

An example

```
var username = "zulu-brain@some.com".split('@')[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wfh4q/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var username = "max@custom.com";
username = username.split('@')[0].replace(/[\W_]/g,"");
```

By splitting the code:

```
username.split('@')[0] // will give all characters before @

.replace(/[\W_]/g,"") // will remove any special character.
```

Comment: Downvoter, I misunderstood the question. I've edited it. Please have a look at it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use **`.split()`** in jquery

```
var username = "max@custom.com";
   console.log(username.split("@")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` will filter the string down to just alphanumeric values and

`replace(/[_\s]/g, '-')` will replace underscores and spaces with hyphens or put '' as it as per your requirement.

For your requirement :

```
string.split("@")[0].replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')
```

[JsFiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/vNfrk/635/)